# Doubt on the second step of the induction principle

Tags: solution-verification, induction, natural-numbers

I have a doubt about the induction principle. Let's prove that $p(n)$ is true $\forall n\geq n_0$.
The *first step* consists in verifying that: $p(n_0)$ is true.
The *inductive step* consists in supposing that $p(n)$ is true and proving that $p(n+1)$ is too.

**Doubt:** if I say that $p(n)$ is true (inductive hypothesis) than can I say that $p(n-1),p(n-2),...$ are true?

Comment: No, but instead of proving that $p(n)$ is true for every $n\geq n_0$ you can go for proving that $q(n)$ is true for every $n\geq n_0$ where $q(n)$ is the statement that $p(k)$ is true for $k=n_0,n_0+1,\dots,n$. This is what they call strong induction. It concerns an enforcement of the induction hypothese.

Comment: See complete (strong) induction here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Comment: Do you mean that I can prove that $p(n+1)$ is true assuming that $p(k)$ is true with $0\leq k\leq n$?

Comment: @drhab I am not sure I have fully understood. Is the following right?                      The *first step* consists in verifying that: $p(n_0)$ is true.\
The *inductive step* consists in supposing that $p(m)$ is true for $m=1,...,n$ and proving that $p(n+1)$ is too.

Comment: @cely Yes, except that at second step in your case you start with $m=n_0$ instead of $m=1$.